# Redirect stdout over ssh

Tags: ssh

I want to redirect the output of a sed command into a .txt file ( in the remote server), the code is as follows:

```
ssh -p XXYY -l root $remoteIP | sed '/keyword/d' /etc/fileA > /etc/fileA_temp
```

I want to update a txt file deleting all the lines that contains a specific keyword and save it in the same file or somewhere where I could after copy it

The first part of the code reply as wanted:

```
ssh -p XXYY -l root $remoteIP | sed '/keyword/d' /etc/fileA
```

But the output in the line command says that **'permission denied'** to the 'fileA_temp' file and shows all the info about the options for ssh...Because of that I think that 'ssh' is not allowing to update the file in some way.

EDIT: Inside the remote server, it works when I tried:

```
sed '/keyword/d' /etc/fileA > /etc/fileA_temp
```

But the console said **'permission denied'** when I run it in a bash script.

Thanks so much

Comment: Why this question was closed as off topic??????? It is related to software development and it was correctly answererd!

Comment: This was a useful question. I'm fed up of stack overflow closing questions that are valid for silly reasons!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you piping the output from ssh into your local sed?

Try this:

```
ssh -p XXYY -l root $remoteIP "sed '/keyword/d' /etc/fileA > /etc/fileA_temp"
```